# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un chequeo de servicios corriendo?

Tags: bash, condiciones, servicio, unix, shell-script

Soy un novato con esto de los scripts en Bash y estoy escribiendo uno para un pequeño servidor PXE, que lo que hace principalmente es una comprobación de los principales servicios importantes del servidor, y mirar si están ejecutándose o no.

El caso es que, después de hacer todos los checks con if, que me costó lo suyo entender su funcionamiento, me gustaría añadir uno, que diferencie entre los que efectivamente están corriendo, y aquellos, que por diversas razones estén parados, y que el mismo script pregunte al usuario, si quiere intentar lanzar los que estén parados, de nuevo.

El código que tengo, es el siguiente:

```
#!bin/bash
# Comprobación de servicios e información sobre el sistema #
sleep 3s;
clear;
echo -n  -e '\e[1;33mComprobando estado de los principales servicios... ';
sleep 1s;
echo -e '\e[1;32m¡LISTO!\n';
sleep 1s;

# Estado Server DHCP #
echo -n -e  '\033[1;36m - Server DHCP - \e[0m';
dhcp=$(systemctl is-active isc-dhcp-server);
if [ $dhcp == "inactive" ]
then
echo -e '   [ \033[1;31m DEAD \e[0m ]\n';
elif [ $dhcp == "active" ]
then
echo -e '   [ \033[1;32m OK \e[0m ]\n';
fi
sleep 1s;

# Estado Server TFTP #
echo -n -e  '\033[1;36m - Server TFTP - \e[0m';
tftpd=$(systemctl is-active tftpd-hpa);
if [ $tftpd == "inactive" ]
then
echo -e '   [ \033[1;31m DEAD \e[0m ]\n';
elif [ $tftpd == "active" ]
then
echo -e '   [ \033[1;32m OK \e[0m ]\n';
fi
sleep 1s;

# Estado Server Apache #
echo -n -e  '\033[1;36m - Server Apache - \e[0m';
apache2=$(systemctl is-active apache2);
if [ $apache2 == "inactive" ]
then
echo -e ' [ \033[1;31m DEAD \e[0m ]\n';
elif [ $apache2 == "active" ]
then
echo -e ' [ \033[1;32m OK \e[0m ]\n';
fi
sleep 1s;

# Estado Server FTP #
echo -n -e  '\033[1;36m - Server FTP - \e[0m';
vsftpd=$(systemctl is-active vsftpd);
if [ $vsftpd == "inactive" ]
then
echo -e '    [ \033[1;31m DEAD \e[0m ]\n';
elif [ $vsftpd == "active" ]
then
echo -e '    [ \033[1;32m OK \e[0m ]\n';
fi
sleep 1s;

# Estado Server WebMin #
echo -n -e  '\033[1;36m - Server Webmin - \e[0m';
webmin=$(systemctl is-active webmin);
if [ $webmin == "inactive" ]
then
echo -e ' [ \033[1;31m DEAD \e[0m ]\n';
elif [ $webmin == "active" ]
then
echo -e ' [ \033[1;32m OK \e[0m ]\n';
fi
sleep 2s;
echo -n -e '\e[1;33mRecopilando información del sistema... ';
sleep 1s;
echo -e '\e[1;32m¡LISTO!\n';
screenfetch;
```

A modo ilustrativo, adjunto imagen para mostrar como se ve una vez que se ha ejecutado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no sé como plantear esto, dado mi escaso conocimiento en scripting.

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, gracias de antemano.

Comment: buen trabajo! Podrías utiilizar funciones para no estar repitiendo muchas líneas de código cada vez.

Comment: realmente sería cuestión de hacer algo así como `if [ $tftpd == "inactive" ]; then read -p "¿Quieres relanzar?" respuesta` y leer luego la variable `$respuesta`.

Comment: Intentaré hacer lo que indicas, pero me costó días el entender como iban los if, else, elseif, elif, y demás. No tengo yo mucha fe de dar en la tecla relativamente pronto, pero gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En cualquiera de los casos puedes decir:

```
dhcp=$(systemctl is-active isc-dhcp-server);

if [ $dhcp == "inactive" ]
then
    read "¿Quieres iniciar el servicio? " si_no
    if [ "$si_no" == "si" ]; then
        systemctl start isc-dhcp-server
    fi
fi
```

---

Nótese por cierto que tu script podría reducirse utilizando funciones:

Una función con parámetros se define por ejemplo como:

```
revisa_servicio () { 
   echo "$1";
}
```

Y se llama con `revisa_servicio "bla" "ble"` (en este caso imprimiría "bla", que es el primer parámetro).

En tu caso concreto, podrías usar dos parámetros: uno para el servicio y otro para el nombre que este tiene.

```
revisa_servicio () {
    echo -n -e  '\033[1;36m - Server "$2" - \e[0m';
    estado_servicio=$(systemctl is-active "$1");
    if [ $estado_servicio == "inactive" ]; then
        echo -e '   [ \033[1;31m DEAD \e[0m ]\n';
    elif [ $estado_servicio == "active" ]; then
        echo -e '   [ \033[1;32m OK \e[0m ]\n';
    fi
    sleep 1s;
}
```

Y lo llamarías por ejemplo diciendo `revisa_servicio "isc-dhcp-server" "DHCP".

Más generalmente, podrías definir un array asociativo para guardar toda la info y así iterar sobre ello:

```
declare -A servicios["TFTP"]="tftpd-hpa" servicios["DHCP"]="isc-dhcp-server"
for servicio in "${!servicios[@]}";
do
    revisa_servicio "${servicios[$servicio]}" "$servicio"
done
```

De esta manera puedes meter tantos servicios como quieras simplemente añadiendo un nuevo `servicios["nombre_del_servicio"]="utilidad-en-systemctl"`.

Comment: Creo que entiendo como funciona ahora que lo veo escrito. Uno de los problemas que tengo con la programación en general, dado que no sé mucho, es que muchas veces, incluso lo más sencillo, se me hace muy cuesta arriba. Muchas gracias, intentaré ver si añadiendo esto al script funciona.

Comment: @AVSalas añadí una generalización. Son muchos conceptos de golpe, así que te sugiero ir bloque a bloque mirándolos con calma. Si tienes dudas, avisa!

Comment: Voy a intentar reescribir el script para añadir tus sugerencias/respuestas e intentar reducirlo también un poco, en cuanto a líneas de código se refiere. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: A ti! Ya explicarás cómo ha ido